# Internal testers, restore purchases and testflight app

Tags: ios, restore, testflight

I have uploaded a new version update of my app into the apple TestFlight, and I have some problems trying to restore purchases:

I'm not able to restore purchases with an internal tester.
I'm not able to restore purchases with a real user.
(some times apple process asks me for the username and pass a couple of times)

I'm able to restore purchases with a sandbox user.
(nice)

I could understand that a real user is not able to restore purchases with my testflight version, but why I'm not able to do it with an internal tester?

Answer (score 2):

solved, you'll get an error if you try to access a sandbox when you logged in as regular account. You must to be unlogged from settings>itunes and then you will be able to restore purchases with an internal user.